# Not Loading Indexed Sources for nuget packages from Azure Devpos during debugging

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

Trying to use azure yml for build pipleline to publish symbols to allow nuget pkg to be debuggable usin azure devops. I see PDB files are donwloaded to the symbols cache folder but stepping thru is asking for source file location in visual studio, even when i have indexed the source code during publish symbol.

I have tried to enable different options in visual studio debugging but nothing seems to help

Here is my yml

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

name: $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r) # need this for byBuildNumber verisonScheme nuget pack
# the build will trigger on any changes to the master branch
trigger:
- master

# the build will run on a Microsoft hosted agent, using the lastest Windows VM Image
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

# these variables are available throughout the build file
# just the build configuration is defined, in this case we are building Release packages
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'


#The build has 3 seperate tasks run under 1 step
steps:

# The first task is the dotnet command build, pointing to our csproj file
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    projects: 'src/Common.Core/Common.Core.csproj'

- task: PublishSymbols@2
  inputs:
    symbolsFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    searchPattern: '**/bin/**/*.pdb' 
    indexSources: true
    publishSymbols: true
    symbolServerType: 'teamServices'        
    treatNotIndexedAsWarning: true 
    symbolsProduct: '$(Build.DefinitionName)'
    symbolsVersion: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    symbolsArtifactName: '$(name).Symbols_$(BuildConfiguration)'

# The second task is dotnet pack command again pointing to the csproj file
# The nobuild means the project will not be compiled before running pack, because its already built in above step
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "dotnet pack"
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    packagesToPack: 'src/Common.Core/Common.Core.csproj'
    nobuild: true
    includeSymbols: true
    versioningScheme: 'byBuildNumber'

# The last task is a nuget command, nuget push
# This will push any .nupkg files to the 'Nuget' artifact feed
# allowPackageConflicts allows us to build the same version and not throw an error when trying to push
# instead it just ingores the latest package unless the version changes
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'nuget push'
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: 'myNuget'
    allowPackageConflicts: true
```

I would expect that when i am debugging nuget packages with symbols enabled with idnexed soruce code, it automatically downloads the pdf file and the source code.

[Visual Studio Settings for debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYv0Q.png)

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I see PDB files are donwloaded to the symbols cache folder but
>   stepping thru is asking for source file location in visual studio,
>   even when i have indexed the source code during publish symbol.

You should let the debugger know where to find your source files. First, please rename your xx.nupkg to xx.zip and check if it contains necessary source files.

After that you can `right-click Solution in Solution Explorer=>Properties=>Debug Source Files`,click the `New Line` option to add the path of your nuget source files to the `debug source files` setting.

> I would expect that when i am debugging nuget packages with symbols
>   enabled with idnexed soruce code, it automatically downloads the pdf
>   file and the source code.

Maybe you can get some help from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880687/how-to-share-source-code-via-nuget-packages-for-use-in-net-core-projects). You can try setting the build action of the source files as `C# compiler` when you create the nuget package for `.net core`.