How to create a custom nuget package in c#with source file as part of the package
i would linke to create a nuget package that allows me to add a file.cs during both install and restore phase of nuget package.
This file must be have as build action "C# Compiler".
I've tryed different approach, but nothing succeded. I managed to copy file to the root of target project (as a link) but its build action is just "content"
Any ideas or example?

"I've tryed different approach" such as what? Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880687/how-to-share-source-code-via-nuget-packages-for-use-in-net-core-projects

Solved!!
In csproj:
    <ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="myfile\myfile.cs">
    <Pack>true</Pack>
    <BuildAction>Compile</BuildAction>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="build\myfile.props">
    <Pack>true</Pack>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>

In props file
  <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\myfile\myfile.cs">
<Link>myfile.cs</Link>
<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
<BuildAction>Compile</BuildAction>

